# What is the best way to store credentials for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, office-365-developer, office-dev-pnp

I will be creating a C# console app that will be executed by a windows task. The purpose of this console app is to prepare a JSON file for [bulk user profile update.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online)

what is the best way to store SPO Admin credentials that will upload the file to Office 365 Tenant?

Answer (score 2):

Windows [Credential](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/How-to-use-the-Windows-Credential-Manager-to-ease-authentication-with-PnP-PowerShell) [Manager](https://practical365.com/blog/saving-credentials-for-office-365-powershell-scripts-and-scheduled-tasks/) is one option. Another option would be to use a file or registry and use [DPAPI](https://github.com/atifaziz/secrets.ps).

There are lots of examples out there, so don't take the above as the absolute only way to work with these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to see other answers, but I personally found this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657792/how-to-securely-save-username-password-local

and ended up using this method from Jon Galloway,

https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

it uses [DPAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)), already mentioned by Trevor.
the key is attached to the user/machine so it will not work in other users/machines (you can request it initially, and then schedule)

the credential manager option looks great, so I don't know. you can have a look at both and see which one is better for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Azure Automation and Runbooks? You can store the credentials in Automation Account Credential store.

Comment: No, I haven't but feel free to share some links. Thanks!

Comment: "Sending you a link" won't help. You have to learn how to use Runbooks and change the way you are running your integration. The PowerShell may be similar but it depends on where/how you are getting your data. Adding credentials is trivial after you get the rest working.